# stabilize hit counter number (aka total visits) on tumblr

Tags: javascript, html, tumblr, hitcounter, tumblr-html

I tried to create a hit counter for my Tumblr.
However it's only changes the number on my main browser, if I switch to other browsers it would reset and not keeping the total number everytime I reload my blog.
Basically it would show that I have 42 visits (because I reloaded it 42 times on my main browser).
But when I open it on other browsers, it resetted to 1 (because it's a new/seperate browser).
Please give me some solution for this! Thank you!

**HTML**

```
<script defer src="hit-counter.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="hit-counter.css" />
    <span class="website-counter"></span>
```

**CSS**

```
.website-counter {
  color: black;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-family: verdana;
}
```

**JavaScript**

```
var counterContainer = document.querySelector(".website-counter");
var visitCount = localStorage.getItem("page_view");

if (visitCount) {
  visitCount = Number(visitCount) + 1;
  localStorage.setItem("page_view", visitCount);
} else {
  visitCount = 1;
  localStorage.setItem("page_view", 1);
}
counterContainer.innerHTML = visitCount;
```

Comment: You're using local storage. That is browser-specific storage. That is, localstorage items stored in Edge won't be reflected in localstorage of Chrome.

Comment: You need to use a centralised datastore, such as a server-side database, not localStorage.

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out as I have yet to understand the whole JS concept.

Comment: Can I ask you what element should be replaced for localStorage? Thank you!