# What elements should be replaced for localStorage?

Tags: javascript, tumblr, tumblr-themes, hitcounter, tumblr-html

I want to create a hit counter for my Tumblr blog. But it failed to show all client numbers as I'm using localStorage. What should I replaced it with? Thank you! 
**CODE**

```
var visitCount = localStorage.getItem("page_view");

if (visitCount) {
  visitCount = Number(visitCount) + 1;
  localStorage.setItem("page_view", visitCount);
} else {
  visitCount = 1;
  localStorage.setItem("page_view", 1);
}
counterContainer.innerHTML = visitCount;
```

Comment: You should replace it with a AJAX call to a backend that stores the values.

Comment: This seems to be a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77193698/stabilize-hit-counter-number-aka-total-visits-on-tumblr.

Comment: You need to look for a third party solution to resolve this. I think it was a thing with Tumblr in the early 2000's, but you need some site that can access a database, plus record visitor hits to your Tumblr. none of this can be done only using the Tumblr platform. There are lots of results here: https://www.google.com/search?q=add+hit+counter+to+tumblr&rlz=1C5CHFA_enGB1077GB1077&oq=add+hit+counter+to+tumblr&gs_lcrp=EgZjaHJvbWUyBggAEEUYOTIHCAEQIRigATIHCAIQIRigAdIBCDUwMDZqMGo3qAIAsAIA&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8 but it's going to be a minefield